# In java, how do I make a loop statement to print the sum of positive nums from 1 to the value assigned to an int from an input from a scanner?

Tags: java

how do I make a loop statement to print the sum of positive numbers from 1 to the value assigned to `int` from input from a scanner?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input a number over value 1 ");
    num = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    
    if (num <= 0) {
        System.out.println("the number has be an Integer");
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "+");
        sum += i;
        // I have no idea what I can do from here one?
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: After the loop simply print the total value like so `System.out.println("The total sum of numbers from 1 to "+num+" is "+sum);`

Comment: Please provide the result you want to achieve and the error or issue that you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getData() {
    System.out.println("Please enter user input  ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    if (input == 0) {
        System.out.println("user input cann't accept.");
    } else {
        int sumValue = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= input; j++) {
            sumValue = sumValue + j;
        }
        System.out.println(sumValue);
    }
}
```